# ASP, MVC, EF: How to map POST values from Html.ListBoxFor<T> to EF Entity Navigation Property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to stackoverflow! Please forgive me if I do something wrong.
I have now searched around hours for a solution, unsuccessfully...
Background:

EF Model "Role":

```
public class IdItem {
    [Key]
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
}
public class NamedItem : IdItem {
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
public class Right : NamedItem {
    ...
}
public class Role : NamedItem {
    /* [1] */ public ICollection<Int32> RightIDs { get; set; } // <-- Key-Collection of Nav-Prop
    /* [2] */ public virtual ICollection<Right> Rights { get; set; } // <-- Nav-Prop
    ...
}
```

View "Roles.cshtml" containing:

```
var sliRights = /* All available Rights as SelectListItem { Value = Right.ID } */
var rightsAtts = new { @class = "form-control selectpicker", multiple = true };
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.RightIDs, sliRights, rightsAtts)
```

This way, the ID's of all selected Rights are correctly stored in the "RightIDs" property of class "Role".

Q: However, how can I tell EF to map the Keys stored in "RightIDs" to synchronously (vice-versa) use it with the "Rights"-Property (see [2])?

I guess something like [ForeignKey("RightIDs")] as att. for [2] (tried, not working)?

**Update**

For example something like:

```
public class Role : NamedItem {
    public ICollection<Int32> RightIDs { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RightIDs")] // <-- normally for non-collections, but tried -> not working at all
    public virtual ICollection<Right> Rights { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Currently, I am using an interface for class "Role" implementing a method to read all IDs from "Rights" into "RightIDs" and another method to perform the way back, both using DbContext as parameter, invoked by responsible controller:

```
public interface IScalarEntity {
    void ToScalarProperties(DbContext context);
    void FromScalarProperties(DbContext context);
}
```

Ugly when using this current approach for at least 20 upcoming entity classes...

**Edit**

As I now have researched, there is no sense to get EF to use a ICollection where T is a primitive type, even if T is a type equal to an key property of another entity Type.

Now going to use the workaround for this kind of problem.

Thanks to all contributors!

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing looks really weird. First of all, you are mixing Database logic with ViewModel logic, which is a bad practice. Do you really need the IDs for the collection of Rights, when you can just get them from the Right object?

You can remove the RightIds property from your **Role** class and use a simple select statement in the controller:

```
var rights = role.Rights.ToList().Select(r => new SelectListItem
                { 
                   Value = r.ID.ToString(),
                   Text = r.Name 
                });
return View(rights);
```

Now in the view you will have a model with SelectListItems, which you can use with many of the List controls available in Razor.

Comment: Sure, the problem is not getting SelectListItem's. Focus on values delivered by posting a form containing the @Html.ListB..., as they only are containing ID values of checked SelectListItem's, which will be correctly available within "RightIDs". The problem is telling EF to perform an (for instance) automatic "Rights.AddRange(context.Set<Right>().Where(x => RightIDs.Contains(x.ID));"